# SQL Server : delete trigger not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2014, sql-delete

Below is table `Country`:

```
+------------------+-----------+
|   COLUMN_NAME    | DATA_TYPE |
+------------------+-----------+
| ID               | int       |
| Name             | varchar   |
| CapitalCity      | varchar   |
| Population       | int       |
| OfficialReligion | varchar   |
| OfficialLanguage | varchar   |
| DateEntered      | datetime  |
+------------------+-----------+
```

I then have another very similar table called `CountryRecord` which has the same columns and then two additional new ones:

```
+-------------------------+-----------+
|   COLUMN_NAME           | DATA_TYPE |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| ID                      | int       |
| OriginalID              | int       |
| Name                    | varchar   |
| CapitalCity             | varchar   |
| Population              | int       |
| OfficialReligion        | varchar   |
| OfficialLanguage        | varchar   |
| DateEntered             | datetime  |
| QueryType               | varchar   |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

When inserting, updating or deleting data in `Country`, a trigger is called that will also insert rows into `CountryRecord` for the purpose of recording what query was made for what row of data. The trigger is as follows:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CountryRecord_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Country]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @CountryID INT, @queryType VARCHAR(20);

    --Update trigger
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        SET @queryType = 'UPDATE';

        SELECT @CountryID = ID FROM inserted i;

        INSERT INTO CountryRecord (OriginalID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion, OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, QueryType) 
            SELECT  
                ID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion, 
                OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, @queryType 
            FROM
                Country 
            WHERE
                @CountryID = ID;
    END

    --Insert trigger
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)       
    BEGIN
        SET @queryType = 'INSERT';

        SELECT @CountryID = ID FROM inserted i;

        INSERT INTO CountryRecord (OriginalID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion, OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, QueryType) 
            SELECT 
                ID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion,
                OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, @queryType 
            FROM
                Country 
            WHERE
                @CountryID = ID;
     END

     --Delete trigger
     IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
     BEGIN
         SET @queryType = 'DELETE';

         SELECT @CountryID = ID FROM deleted d;

         INSERT INTO CountryRecord (OriginalID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion, OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, QueryType) 
             SELECT 
                 ID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion,
                 OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, @queryType 
             FROM
                 Country 
             WHERE
                 @CountryID = ID;
     END
```

However, while the Insert and Update triggers work, the Delete trigger does not. When I run a delete query, I pick only one row, so I'm fairly sure that the delete query is not selecting more than one row (instead, seems like it's selecting nothing, since doing a check of the current identity of `CountryRecord` after running the delete query shows it hasn't increased by one).

**Update:** Changing the delete trigger to use `ELSE` instead of meeting the condition set does not fix the issue. Instead, any update queries will call both the update and delete trigger, while delete queries still have no effect.

**Update 2:** Just to check that I was only affecting one row, I added in select queries for each trigger as well as a print of `@CountryID` - the select queries showed only 1 row, while `@CountryID` did not come up as null/blank. I also tried altering the columns thinking if the NOT NULL constraint had any effect, but it didn't.

**Update 3:** I have got Delete working now, although it only works for single row deletes. Multi row deletes do not work properly - if for example I delete two records, only one row goes into the audit table. I have also updated Insert and Update to use a similar code structure, so they also have the same multi row issue. Code snippet for the delete portion:

```
SET @queryType = 'DELETE';
SELECT CountryID = ID FROM deleted;
INSERT INTO CountryRecord (OriginalID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion, OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, QueryType) 
    SELECT ID, Name, CapitalCity, Population, OfficialReligion, OfficialLanguage, DateEntered, @queryType FROM deleted WHERE @CountryID = ID;
DECLARE @auditID int;
SET @auditID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
UPDATE CountryRecord SET QueryType = @queryType WHERE ID = @auditID;
```

Comment: You are making trigger mistake number one: assuming that `INSERTED` and `DELETED` have only one row - they don't. Also your audit table probably doesn't need all of those columns

Comment: I added in a select query for both `INSERTED` and `DELETED` - the results showed only 1 row. Currently all I'm doing is inserting, updating and deleting the same single row with the same ID. I also did a `PRINT` of `@CountryID` - in each trigger, the `@CountryID` was not null/blank.

Comment: That's fine but you should be trying to fix code that already has other bugs in it. If you get this working you still have to fix the multirow bug. What you want to do can be achieved in _one_ insert statement. There are many examples on stackoverflow. I'll find one

Comment: The reason your delete doesn't work is because the record has already been deleted from the `country` table. You need to get it from the `deleted` table instead. Same goes for your other two. It's a bad idea to refer to the source tables in a trigger.

Comment: Have a think about how you could write one query from the `inserted` and `deleted` tables that does everything that you want, in one query, no matter how many records are in `inserted` and `deleted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your delete doesn't work is because the record has already been deleted from the `country` table. So you can't select it out of there.

You need to get it from the `deleted` table instead.

Your other two queries also refer to the `Country` tables in a trigger which is a bad idea. You shouldn't use the source table in your query - you should use `inserted` and `deleted` instead.

Have a think about how you could write one query from the inserted and deleted tables that does everything that you want, in one query, no matter how many records are in inserted and deleted. If you don't abandon this question (it happens a lot), I will add an example to this answer.

Here is a query that saves your inserts and updates in one go:

```
INSERT INTO CountryRecord (
 Name, 
 CapitalCity, 
 Population, 
 OfficialReligion, 
 OfficialLanguage, 
 DateEntered, 
 QueryType)
SELECT 
 I.Name, 
 I.CapitalCity, 
 I.Population, 
 I.OfficialReligion, 
 I.OfficialLanguage,
 GETDATE() As DateEntered, 
 CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED D WHERE D.ID = I.ID) 
   THEN 'U' ELSE 'I' 
 END As QueryType
 FROM INSERTED I
```

I have left out `OriginalID` because people you should not be updating the primary key and besides, its impossible to work out what was updated in this case. You can only do that in a BEFORE trigger

Here's one that captures your deletes. I've done these separately so they are easier to understand, and will probably perform better for large recordsets

```
INSERT INTO CountryRecord (
 Name, 
 CapitalCity, 
 Population, 
 OfficialReligion, 
 OfficialLanguage, 
 DateEntered, 
 QueryType)
SELECT 
 D.Name, 
 D.CapitalCity, 
 D.Population, 
 D.OfficialReligion, 
 D.OfficialLanguage,
 GETDATE() As DateEntered, 
 'D' As QueryType
 FROM DELETED D
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED I WHERE I.ID = D.ID)
```

These will work regardless of how many rows have been altered

If you want to actually check which columns changed in an update, you can again compare them individually in the select statement, or you can use the `UPDATED()` function

Is this a school question? Because triggers are really a last resort, but people insist on teaching them in school still even though they are mostly irrelevant.

What is *relevant* is the set based solution I have posted here

Comment: That makes sense. Although I do also have the issue where I have the additional column `queryType` which is not in `INSERTED` or `DELETED` - I am working on getting that value alongside the others.

Comment: Yes you can also do that in one query

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the `MERGE` functionality. One thing with that - for `UPDATE`, do you need to specify in the condition every single column between source and target possibly not being the same? Eg. `WHEN MATCHED AND Target.Name <> Source.Name OR Target.CapitalCity <> Source.CapitalCity` and so on. This would be rather problematic for larger tables.

Comment: You're only inserting rows into the audit table so `merge` is unecessary (it's usually unnecessary). You just need to get the `select` statement right and insert that straight into your audit table. I'll edit my question a bit later with a suggestion.

Comment: At the moment, I do have a modified version of the trigger query which has `DELETE` working (I'll include a snippet of that in the OP), but it still has the problem where it does not work properly for multiple rows affected. Besides `MERGE`, I have also thought of using loops (`WHILE`), but that is still only doing one by one inserts into the audit table.

Comment: Hint: ‘insert into country record select * from inserted’ will put all of those inserted rows into the table in one go. Neither merge nor while loops are part of the solution. Just having dinner now but see if you can find the solution before me. There are many examples, they’re just hard to find.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realise this solution sooner...even worse is I've used it many times before. What works for copying from one table to another works just the same for copying from `INSERTED` and `DELETED`, I just failed to put two and two together. Many thanks for helping me to realise my absentmindedness.